# Angular 4 *ngif conditional check

Tags: angular, angular5

I need to check a value for negative 1 that I use for failure but I don't want to display that value.  Instead I want to display either "N/A" or "--" but I am new to angular and not sure how.  My material table is listed below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Milliseconds">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Milli seconds </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let latency"> {{latency.Milliseconds}} </mat-cell>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read up on template syntax? Pipes?

Comment: Your question is not understandable..Please make the question more specific with your existing code..

Comment: Still does not change the display value.  Not sure if it matters but the value is a string and not numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let latency">{{ latency.Milliseconds === -1 ? '--' : latency.Milliseconds }}</mat-cell>
```

Comment: Glad I could help :) Consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark so others know your question has been answered. Welcome to SO!